# How Do You Use the Redeye tool in Photoshop CS5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5, tools

I applied the redeye tool for my image, but after applying it, I do not see any major difference… How can I remove the red eyes in that image?

Comment: How did you apply it? Did you click on the red eye areas? Did you try adjusting the pupil size and darken amount values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply select the Red Eye Tool, then click-drag on the image to draw a box around the red eye... you may need to click-drag a couple times to get the entire eye.

[image: Red Eye Tool]

Perhaps a better method is to use the Desaturation Tool and simply brush away the color yourself. All the Red Eye Tool does is apply desaturation to the center portion of the area you click-drag to create. By using the Desaturation Tool, you have far more control over the amount of desaturation in addition to the actual area of desaturation.

Comment: Good answer! How do you get these animations? Wonderful idea!

Comment: If this solves the issue you should mark it as the correct answer. The animation is created via a screen capture utility which saves a movie file. Then the movie file is opened in Photoshop Extended and saved as an animated gif.